# Execution failed for Task: ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, eas

I've tried building my expo managed project with firebase installed, but seem to get the following error:
Execution failed for task: ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Here's my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "lightandlovetribe",
    "owner": "lightandlovetribe",
    "slug": "doApp-432Hz",
    "version": "1.5.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/mandala.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash_screen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.markcash11.Solfeggiomusicplayer"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.markcash11.Solfeggiomusicplayer",
      "versionCode": 19
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app"
    ],
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "487b08ab-4d87-451f-82f1-5dcf7741343a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "solfeggio_music_player",
  "version": "1.5.2",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^5.5.0",
    "cross-spawn": "^7.0.3",
    "expo": "^49.0.13",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-haste-map": "^29.7.0",
    "jotai": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-core": "^0.79.1",
    "nice-try": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^10.1.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-music-control": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "recyclerlistview": "^3.0.5",
    "sentry-expo": "~7.0.0",
    "walker": "^1.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've tried (according to another thread) reinstalling @react-native-firebase/app with 'npm remove' and 'npm install --save' and tried running: 'npx jetify' but to no avail.

Could anyone help me build this APP?
Maybe the problem is due to the fact that I'm building with

`eas build --profile development --platform android`?
Or that converting to AndroidX failes partially (but npx jetify should fix that)

All help is appreciated!